# How do you customize UIMenu as horizontal?

Tags: ios, swift, uimenu

I’m creating an app that has a `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIMenu`.

Is there any way to customize menu entries to show horizontally and put text under the icon? I tried to read the Apple documents but I couldn’t find the way.

The iOS Notes app has a similar menu (Scan, Pin, Lock):

[image]

If you know how to do this, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a `UIMenu` look like the one in your screenshot where there are three buttons in the first row, change your menu's [`preferredElementSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenu/4013313-preferredelementsize) to [`UIMenu.ElementSize.medium`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenu/elementsize/medium). Note that `preferredElementSize` is only available in iOS 16.0+.

```swift
yourMenu.preferredElementSize = .medium
```